# Metric of positive curvature and Homology group

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Is it possible to decide that whether the manifold $M$ admit a metric of positive curvature by knowing all Homology group of $M$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. For example, $S^9$ admits a metric of constant positive sectional curvature, but there is an exotic $9$-sphere $\Sigma$ (i.e. $\Sigma$ is a smooth manifold homeomorphic to $S^9$, but not diffeomorphic to it) which does not even admit a metric of positive scalar curvature. As $S^9$ and $\Sigma$ are homeomorphic, they have the same homology groups.

Comment: Sorry.. so late.. but what about up to homeomorphic (or homotopy)?

Comment: @C.F.G: I am not sure what you mean by 'up to' in this case. I gave an example of two homeomorphic manifolds, one which admits a metric of positive curvature, and one which does not.

Comment: I mean, If we consider these two case $S^9$ and $\Sigma$ (and similar cases) equal (topologically they are one) then what is the answer?

Comment: The answer is different for these two.

Answer (score 4):

**Definition.** A manifold $M$ is called an $n$-dimensional homology sphere if its homology groups are isomorphic to that of $S^n$ (i.e. $M$ is connected and its homology is nonzero only in degrees 0 and n).

There are many examples of **integer homology spheres** in dimension 3 which are **apherical** (i.e. have contractible universal covering space). The simplest example I know is obtained as follows: Take the trefoil knot $K\subset S^3$, let $N$ be the complement in $S^3$ to a regular neighborhood of $K$. The boundary of $N$ is $T^2$. Now, glue two copies of $N$ by swapping the meridians and longitudes. MV sequence shows that the resulting manifold $M$ is a 3-dimensional homology sphere. With a bit more work, one verifies that $M$ is aspherical.

There are many other examples like this, for instance, among 
hyperbolic 3-manifolds.

According to Thm. 8.1 in

M. Gromov, H.B. Lawson, Positive scalar curvature and the Dirac operator on complete Riemannian manifolds, Inst. Hautes Etudes Sci. Publ. ´Math. No. 58 (1983), 83–196.

such a manifold cannot admit a metric of positive scalar curvature.